# Calling function in one contract from another contract in private blockchain by Geth

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, ethereum-classic, geth-debugging

I have problem with smart contract development using Remix solidity in private blockchain by Geth. I have two smart contracts such as Factory contract and Contract contract.

I create the Factory contract and then I call the createContract and getContract function, it works normally but when i call the getNum function I can not get the number.

I run this code in Remix solidity by JavaScript VM and Test network by Ganache or TestRPC work fine but when i use it with Private blockchain using Geth it has this problem

Here is my code.

```
contract Factory {
  address[] newContracts;

  function createContract(uint num) {
    address newContract = new Contract(num);
    newContracts.push(newContract);
  }

  function getContract() view public returns(address[]) {
    return newContracts;
  }

  function getNum(address _add) view public returns(uint) {
    return Contract(_add).getNum();
  }
}


contract Contract {
  uint public Num;

  function Contract(uint num) {
    Num = num;
  }

  function getNum() public returns(uint) {
    return Num;
  }
}
```

[image: the picture of smartcontract problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Contract` add view-modifier to `getNum`

```
function getNum() public view returns(uint) {
    return Num;
}
```

Your calls worked in ganache/testrpc/remix because the test EVM is synchronous in nature. I.e., you'll be able to get return values of transactions, since `sendTransaction` calls are executed instantly.

[image]

Comment: I add view modifier to getNum in Contract but it still work the same problem !

Comment: yes  ! I put the address with double-quotes.

Comment: I used the remix solidity with private blockchain using Geth not with JavaScript VM

Comment: Sorry.. Safari reseted my connection to JavaScript VM due to http/https. Anyway, it works with Web3 Provider and geth node with Clique PoA. Everything is fine (see updated screenshot).

Comment: I think maybe I have problem to setup private blockchain by Geth. so do you know which way to setup private blockchain by Geth correctly.

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8 — check out this post if you have problems in setting up a PoA Clique network.

Comment: now it works fine and easy to use than before